# Conditionally constructing a list with immutable.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

Our code base has been striving to use consts instead of lets, and using immutable.js whenever possible. It's been surprisingly easy for the most part, although I found this piece of code that looked wrong, but couldn't think of a better way to do this without mutating an array and just doing List(arr). The code is simplified to the bare needed to make my point.

```
const item1 = item1Condition ? Map(...) : null;
const item2 = item2Condition ? Map(...) : null;
const item3 = item3Condition ? Map(...) : null;
return List([item1, item2, item3]).filter(item => item != null);
```

Normally I would do something like

```
const arr = [];
if (condition1) arr.push(Map(...));
...
return List(arr);
```

But that doesn't feel very immutable-y. Is there a more immutable way to make a list like this?

Comment: It seems a folly to create an array with a bunch of `null` in it and then filter out the `null` entries into a new array just to avoid modifying an array for some immutable pursuit.  It seems some abstract objective has gotten in the way of just writing the most straightforward code.  There is NO rule that says only using immutable data structures is always the best way to write code.  In fact, making an entirely new copy of a data structure just so you can make a simple modification, but not mutate the original may be entirely inefficient in many circumstances.

Comment: If you can show us a bit greater context here with some real code, not just pseudo code, we can probably provide a better answer.  I don't believe it's necessarily best to create lots of temporary data structures just to follow some immutable pattern when you could just build the one data structure you need by modifying it.

Comment: Immutability is a good property to have at the function level. It often makes a function pure i.e. predictable and easy to test.
Immutability is a means to get to pure functions.
Doesn't mean you can't create temporary objects and mutate them.
Since you create the array, you are the sole owner and as long as you don't hold onto it, can create it any way you choose.

Comment: ^ That's a good insight @JochenBedersdorfer

Answer (score 0):

I would solve your problem using a combination of `zip` and `reduce`, for example like this:

```js
function zip(a, b) {
  return a.map(function(e, i) {
    return [e, b[i]];
  });
}

function doStuff(conditions, values) {
  return zip(conditions, values).reduce(function(res, el) {
    if(el[0]) {
      return [...res, el[1]];
    } 
    return res;
  }, []);
}

let conditions = [true, false, true];
let values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
console.log(doStuff(conditions, values));
```

Either that or you could use your solution with something like the [`compact` function from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#compact)

Comment: How is this simpler than `if (condition1) arr.push(Map(...));`?  And, how is this even close to as efficient?  It appears that for an N element final array, you create at least N-1 temporary arrays along the way.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP said he wanted it to "feel more immutable-y". I don't actually think that this solution is either better nor worse than what OP already has. Its just another way of thinking about the same problem. How are we to know what "feels immutable-y" to OP?

Comment: @jfriend00 Also, i upvoted your comment. I agree with you. But another perspective has never hurt any one.

Comment: I'm reacting to the OP's goal of being immutable-y without regard for readability, simplicity and all other general programming goals.  I don't always answer questions purely literal here when I think their question is headed in a wrong direction.  I try to point them in a better direction and I thought that was what was needed here.

Comment: @jfriend000 Now what? Would you have me delete my answer? Because you don't believe OP deserves one?

Comment: I think answers should show the OP a better way to meet their coding goal (not necessary using immutability) and explain why it's a better way to code.  You and I both know that building a 1000 element array by creating 999 temporary arrays is not an efficient way to code.  I didn't downvote your answer.  I asked you a question in a comment to explain why this is a good way to code which you did not answer.   The best answers don't only supply an answer to the literal question asked.  The best answers understand the overall problem and provide the best way to solve that problem.

Comment: @jfriend000 I don't believe that it is our job, nor place, to educate OP, especially not in subjects that are out of scope for the question at hand. I believe in short and concise answers strictly relevant to the asked question, witch in this case was "Is there a more immutable way to make a list like this?". However we most definitely do not have to agree on any of this.

Comment: People come here with a problem to solve.  They are often pursuing the wrong solution to their problem.  I think it's more valuable to understand the actual problem and give them the best programming solution to the problem and perhaps even explain why the approach they asked about in the question is off target.  But, you're welcome to your own opinion.  You asked me to explain my comments so I did.  We can agree to disagree.